# Prevent Angular route from redirecting to landing page on adding data to firestore database

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, routes

I am using cloud firestore sdk in my angular application. I have setup a subscription to user data valueChanges().
I have added a method through which users can follow each other. In the backend, everything is working fine. But, as soon as I click the follow button, route gets redirected to the landing page.

I want the user to stay in the same page, from where they clicked the button.

app.component.ts ->

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.initAuthStateListener();
  }
```

authService->

```
initAuthStateListener(){
    this.loadStateChanged.next(true);
    return this.afAuth.authState
    .subscribe(
      user=>{
        if(user){
          this.isAuthenticated =true;
          this.authChange.next(true);
          this.authSubs.push(
          this.userService.fetchUserDetails(user.uid).subscribe(
            user=>{
              this.router.navigate(['/training']);
            }
          ));
        }
        else{
          this.cancelAllSubs();
          this.isAuthenticated = false;
          this.authChange.next(false);
          this.router.navigate(['']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

.ts page ->

```
onFollow(){
    this.userService.followUser(this.user.userid,this.user.email);
  }
```

userService ->

```
userData = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
private user:User;

fetchUserDetails(uid:string){
    return this.db.collection("Users").doc(uid).valueChanges()
    .pipe(tap((user:User)=>{
      this.user = user;
      console.log(this.user);
      this.userData.next({...this.user});
    }));
  }

followUser(uid:string,email:string){
    this.db.collection('Users').doc(this.user.userid)
      .update({
        following:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
           {'uid':uid,'email':email})
        });
    this.db.collection('Users').doc(uid)
      .update({
        followers:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
           {'uid':this.user.userid,'email':this.user.email})
        });
  }

 getUserData(){
    return ({...this.user});
  }
```

'training' is my landing route, when the user if logged in. In AppComponent, I have added a check to verify if the user token exists, and based on that user is either redirected to training to null route.
But, it seems like, every time there is some change in user data it is redirecting me back to the training (landing) route.

Comment: You need to post some code..

Comment: Added the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to provided code, nothing has relation to routing, check your HTML button, it may have a `routerLink` or `href` that directs you to your landing page, If no,
check your `initAuthStateListener` function maybe user is not authenticated so that it directs you to home page as you wrote `this.router.navigate(['']);`, anyway the only code that may directs you to your landing page is in your `initAuthStateListener` function

Comment: No, there are no redirects in my button.

Comment: <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onFollow()">
              Follow
 </button>

Comment: Check your `initAuthStateListener` function maybe user is not authenticated so that it directs you to home page as you wrote   `this.router.navigate(['']);`

Comment: After successful login, I have three different routes, training as a landing page, a users route, where I see list of users and a details route, where I can see details of selected user and click on follow button to follow them. As soon as I click on follow button, the list of followers and following get updated, and I am redirected to the training route.

Comment: Well, now i understand, the routing happens here 
` this.router.navigate(['/training']); `
so if you want to stay in the same page, remove the code line above

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I replaced the navigation from `initAuthStateListener` to my welcome component.

Comment: You are welcome ^_^, good luck and upvote my Comment so that anyone need help see it, or i will update my answer and mark it as right one, Thanks ^^